# ansible error. windows node are unreachable

Tags: amazon-ec2, redhat, windows-server-2012, ansible-2.x

after setting up my ansilbe on aws ec2. I am able to talk to my linux ec2 but having issues with my windows ec2.

On the remote windows server

```
PS C:\Users\name.domain> Winrm quickconfig
WinRM service is already running on this machine.
WinRM is already set up for remote management on this computer.
```

On my linux host that has Ansible installed:

```
# klist
Ticket cache: FILE:/tmp/krb5cc_0
Default principal: user_name@domain.local

Valid starting       Expires              Service principal
09/19/2016 10:02:18  09/19/2016 20:02:18  krbtgt/DOMAIN.LOCAL@DOMAIN.LOCAL
renew until 09/26/2016 10:02:12


/etc/ansible/hosts

[local]
127.0.0.1

[windows]
ip address 

[windows:vars]
ansible_user= name@Domain.com
ansible_password= password
ansible_port= 5985
ansible_connection= winrm
```

This is the Error

```
 # ansible windows -m win_ping
   ip_address | UNREACHABLE! => {
   "changed": false,
   "msg": "kerberos: requested auth method is kerberos, but    requests_kerberos    is not installed, ssl:    HTTPSConnectionPool(host='ip_address', port=5986): Max   retries exceeded with    url: /wsman (Caused by       ConnectTimeoutError(<requests.packages.urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnectio       n object at 0x3585d90>, 'Connection to ip_address timed out. (connect   timeout=30)'))",
   "unreachable": true
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems, that Ansible tries to connect to your Windows EC2 with Kerberos. I assume this is because your `ansible_user` contains this *@Domain.com*. First question: Do you really want to use Kerberos / Active Directory? I would advice to go with a local administrator account at the first step which is much easier. See the full example here: https://github.com/jonashackt/ansible-windows-springboot (which uses Vagrant, but I think you can easily adapt for AWS).

Or second - if you need Active Directory support - did you configure everything correctly, like the [docs are stating](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/intro_windows.html#active-directory-support)? The error seems to relate to the first step discribed there, where you have to install requests_kerberos via:

```
pip install kerberos requests_kerberos
```